# List comprehension with if condition in python

Tags: python

I have a list which has elements of type int and str. I need to copy the int elements to another list. I tried a list comprehension which is not working. My equivalent loop is working.

```
input = ['a',1,'b','c',2,3,'c','d']
output = []
[output.append(a) for a in input if type(a) == int]
```

[None, None, None]

same logic in loop works.

```
output = []
for a in input:
    if type(a) == int:
        output.append(a)
print(output)
```

[1,2,3,]

Can I know what made the difference.

Comment: Your logic does work, just `print(output)` at the end.

Comment: well your list comprehension never got any values, it just kept giving them to output, just write a if instead of 'output.append(a)' if you want them to go the list comprehensoion

Comment: Your original code works fine.

Answer (score 10):

When you're doing:

```
input = ['a',1,'b','c',2,3,'c','d']
output = []
[output.append(a) for a in input if type(a) == int]
```

`append` returns `None`, so that's why lot of none's

Btw,:

```
print(output)
```

Will be desired result.

Your logic actually works!

But it's not good to use list comprehension as side-effects, so best way would be:

```
output=[a for a in input if type(a) == int]
```

Also final best would be `isinstance`:

```
output=[a for a in input if isinstance(a,int)]
```

Answer (score 3):

An idiomatic solution would be:

```
    input = ['a', 1, 'b', 'c', 2, 3, 'c', 'd']
    output = [a for a in input if type(a) == int]
```

You do not want to use output.append. That is implied by the list comprehension. 
You can change the first a in the comprehension to an expression containing a.
output.append(a) is a method call that returns NONE

Use list comprehensions when you want to collect values into a list you are assigning to a variable or as part of larger expression. Do not use them for side effects as a different format for a 'for loop'. Instead use the for loop.

Spaces after the commas are not required but are considered good style.

Answer (score 2):

```
input = ['a',1,'b','c',2,3,'c','d']
output = [a for a in input if type(a) == int]
```

The list comprehension automatically creates the list - no need to use `append()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to solve your problem:

```
output = [a for a in input if type(a) == int]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be:

```
input = ['a',1,'b','c',2,3,'c','d']
output=[item for item in input if type(item) is int]  or
output=[item for item in input if isinstance(item,int)]
```

and the last one is quicker than the first.

but when you use:

```
input = ['a',1,'b','c',2,3,'c','d']
output=[]
[output.append(a) for a in input if type(a) == int]
```

it means the code execute two results ,the one is **output.append(a)** append object in end    and the **list comprehension** with if condition creates a new list object after executing ,as a.append()(**Look_in_IDLE**) return **None** , so there are three None.